# Display recent login failures on login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I have an Ubuntu Linux server that is web facing.  Because of this I get a fair number of brute force SSH attempts (who doesn't). I'd like to display the last N failed login attempts at my login prompt. I've worked out the simple script:

```
grep "Failed" /var/log/auth.log | tail -5
```

but what I need to know is where do I put this line of script? Is there somewhere to put it that's shell agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing was creating a `.profile.d` directory in my home directory, and copying the execution loop from `/etc/profile` to my `$HOME/.profile`.  I then placed my `displayAttacks.sh` script into my `$HOME/.profile.d` directory (as well as my other init scripts).

The addition to `.profile` follows.

```
if [ -d "${HOME}/.profile.d" ]; then
  for i in ${HOME}/.profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
      . "$i"
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of packages that you can use to help with brute force attacks.

1. Denyhosts
2. Fail2ban

To collect logs and send you a report you can use logwatch.  It can send a summary of failed logons as well.

To answer your original question you can put your script in "/etc/profile.d/yourscript.sh" and it should be executed on login.

You might also consider setting up the arno-iptables-firewall package.

Comment: or, just add it to the bottom of your .profile, if you only want to do it for a single user.

Comment: fail2ban is good to use. I've set on my latest vps my firewall to limit the number of ssh connections from a single ip within a time frame. So ufw limit ssh this means if someone tries to brute force ssh they have to slow down the attempt if not the firewall will ban them for a bit.

Comment: +1 and thanks for fail2ban, using that in addition to my script now.

Answer (score 2):

It's really shell dependent. For `bash`, you should put it in `.bash_login` file.

Regarding brute force atack prevention, aside from what's already been sugested for blacklisting the attacker's IP, I usually tell sshd to listen on a nonstandard port and disable the password authentication. Of course, that might not always be possible, but it sure is effective.

Comment: your .profile should be sourced by almost every modern shell.

Comment: +1 - the only response that I think answers the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in /etc/profile.

It will run everything in /etc/profile before going to your shell startup file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, so I might be wrong, but wouldn't be better to create a script in the `/etc/profile.d` directory?

Comment: I use Fedora Linux and in my /etc/profile file, there is a loop that runs everything in the /etc/profile.d directory. You should check if your /etc/profile will process everything in this directory, otherwise you will have to declare directly in the file.

Comment: I used this for a while, but after adding non-admin users, it causes errors on their login, so I needed to move it somewhere local to my user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [perl script](http://www.bsdconsulting.no/tools/sshblock-1.0.pl), [SSHBlock](http://shellscripts.org/project/sshblock) that can be used against brute forcing SSH.
It follows a frequent attempt from an IP address and slows down their attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in there. First, any non-root user should not be able to read the auth log file. If you are logging in as root, don't do it anymore :)

Second, use a proper tool for that. I like [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net)'s approach to email me for every X number of failed logins within a period of time. It also blocks the ip automatically, reducing the chance of a brute-force attack succeeding.

Comment: I'm not root, but I am in the `admin` group, which allows access.